# Calculator Web Application Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I need to make a calculator for school but when I click on button 1 number 1 is not coming into the textbox.

This is the aspx code I have:

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // controleer of er minder dan 7 tekens staan
    if (txtScherm.Text.Length < 7)
    {
        txtScherm.Text += "1";
    }
}
```

```html
<asp:Table ID="Table2" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtScherm"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>

<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="7" Height="50" Width="50" /></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" Text="8" Height="50" Width="50" /></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:Button ID="btn3" runat="server" Text="9" Height="50" Width="50" /></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:Button ID="btn4" runat="server" Text="C" Height="50" Width="50" /></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell><asp:Button ID="btn5" runat="server" Text="Back" Height="50" Width="50" /></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
```

Comment: It seems you don't assign the btn1_Click Event

Comment: Add this to your `Button`: `OnClick="btn1_Click"`

Answer (score 2):

You have to modify your code like this :

```
<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="7" Height="50" Width="50" OnClick="btn1_Click"/>
```

and do the same for all your buttons with the right event.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set the Click Event for btn1:

change:

```
<asp:TableCell><asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="7" Height="50" Width="50" /></asp:TableCell>
```

to:

```
<asp:TableCell><asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="7" Height="50" Width="50" Click="btn1_Click"/></asp:TableCell>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add OnClick="btn1_Click" as Shown Below

`<asp:TableCell><asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="7" Height="50" Width="50" OnClick="btn1_Click"/></asp:TableCell>`